# How to install a maven build project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, installation

I want to install the following plugin:

https://github.com/AgileReview-Project/AgileReview-EclipsePlugin

Its a maven project. I already successfully build the plugin with maven. Now, I want to install it.

How can I install it? When I build the file with Maven, no Jar file was created that I can use for installation.

Comment: Look for *.jar files in target directory of any sub-directories of this project.

Comment: Almost all sub directories have .jar files in their respective Target folder. Which Jar file should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pom` is container of sub-modules, I see a lot of sub-directories in the project.

Somewhere, nested within the project structure you will find artifacts (modules) with jar packaging. Maven generally builds everything into `/target` subdirectories of each module. So after mvn install look into target subdirectory in a module with jar packaging.

Comment: Doesn't it means different jar file for different directories? Then, which jar files I will install? Should be there only one jar file for total plugin installation?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have (https://github.com/AgileReview-Project/AgileReview-EclipsePlugin) is the actual work code project of the plugin. (It is only interesting for the people working on the plugin or others who want to change/improve it).

According to AgileReview website, you'll have to simply do the old-way plugin installation. All the steps and infos are [here](http://www.agilereview.org/download/)

Comment: Well, I am interested in improving the plugin. Thats why I need to work with the plugin project instead of direct installation from marketplace